# Powershell Install-Package from Nuget

Tags: powershell, docker

I'm trying to follow Docker installation guide for Windows server 2016 (https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/). When I execute

```
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
```

there is an error

> Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'DestinationPath'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Verbos ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package],
>   Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToDownload,Install-Package,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Seems like the package is found and downloaded but wrong install command is called for some reason. Any way to fix it? Here is the full verbose output for Install-Package command:

> VERBOSE: Using the provider 'DockerMsftProvider' for searching
>   packages. 
>   VERBOSE: Download size: 0MB 
>   VERBOSE: Free space on the
>   drive: 166058.04MB VERBOSE: Downloading
>   https://dockermsft.blob.core.windows.net/dockercontainer/DockerMsftIndex.json
>   to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Do
>   ckerMsftProvider\DockerDefault_DockerSearchIndex.json VERBOSE: About
>   to download VERBOSE: Finished downloading VERBOSE: Downloaded in 0
>   hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds. VERBOSE: Performing the operation
>   "Install Package" on target "Package 'Docker' version
>   '1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta' from 'DockerDefault'.". VERBOSE: Containers
>   feature is already installed. Skipping the install. VERBOSE: Download
>   size: 13.53MB VERBOSE: Free space on the drive: 166058.04MB VERBOSE:
>   Downloading
>   https://dockermsft.blob.core.windows.net/dockercontainer/docker-1-12-2-cs2-ws-beta.zip
>   to C:\Users\me\AppData\Loca
>   l\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\Docker-1-12-2-cs2-ws-beta.zip VERBOSE: About
>   to download VERBOSE: Finished downloading VERBOSE: Downloaded in 0
>   hours, 0 minutes, 9 seconds. VERBOSE: Verifying Hash of the downloaded
>   file. VERBOSE: Hash verified! VERBOSE: Found
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\Docker-1-12-2-cs2-ws-beta.zip
>   to install. VERBOSE: Trying to unzip :
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\Docker-1-12-2-cs2-ws-beta.zip
>   VERBOSE: Removing the archive:
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\DockerMsftProvider\Docker-1-12-2-cs2-ws-beta.zip
>   Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'DestinationPath'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Verbos ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package],
>   Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToDownload,Install-Package,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

UPD:
Seems like the problem is with this line:

```
$null = Expand-Archive -Path $destination -DestinationPath $env:ProgramFiles -Force
```

But when called directly the Expand-Archive command is executed fine

Answer (score 3):

You may not have to totally uninstall. If you have a PowerShell profile you can forcibly load the "standard" `Expand-Archive` command first, then tell PowerShell Community Extensions to not replace it:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
Import-Module Pscx -NoClobber
```

After that, you should be able to `Get-Command Expand-Archive` and you'll see the source is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive` rather than `Pscx`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I was due to the Powershell Community Extensions that I installed... There is a conflict on the command Expand-Archive with recent Powershell version.

Comment: Brilliant, would never have thought of this, thank you.  Uninstalled, rebooted, problem fixed.